# My cat recently started to snort when yawning. Should I be worried?

Tags: cats, ears-nose-throat, upper-respiratory-disease

My cat recently started to snort when yawning. Not every time he yawns, but frequent enough to catch my attention. I think the first time I noticed that was about 1 month ago, but he always breathes quite loud when he sleeps, and moans every now and then. Never hear him breathing loud or moaning when he's awake though. He's not overweight (4.8kg British shorthair), and the vet tells me he's all healthy. Should I be worried?

Comment: Moaning when asleep: could just be snoring. My cat does this. ... Snorting: Seasonal allergies? If the vet says don't worry, I wouldn't worry.